# Bytes to dict conversion

Tags: python, json, dictionary, byte

I have a list of dict objects. I converted the dict object inside list to bytes by converting dict to str and then encode them.

```
    for idx, key in enumerate(key_data):
        key_data[idx] = str(key).encode('utf-8')
    for idx, value in enumerate(value_data):
        value_data[idx] = str(value).encode('utf-8')

    test = key_data[0]
    test = json.loads(test.decode('utf-8').replace("'",'"'))
```

But when I try to convert them back, I'm getting JSON error " json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 183 (char 182) "

Do I need to add anything to my string ? Help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Even after replacing the quotation marks your data is not valid JSON. Always use the `json` nodule to create JSON!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KlausD suggested, Python has an inbuilt module [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to serialize or deserialize any JSON or python dictionaries. If you have a list of JSON objects, it is nothing but a JSON array.

> The python module json converts a python dict object into JSON objects, whereas the list and tuple are converted into JSON array. A python str is converted into a JSON string. Integers and floating-point numbers are converted into JSON numbers. The Boolean value True is converted into JSON constant true.

In your case, you can serialize by calling

```
encoded = json.dumps(key_data).encode()
```

And deserialize by calling

```
decoded = json.loads(encoded.decode())
```